# Document mutually exclusive defines

Tags: c, comments, doxygen, cperl-mode

I'm writing a small program in **C** and I want to document it so others could change some details. I wrote a config.h file with `#define`s that enable some operation or not, some of them are mutually exclusive, others aren't.

Example of not mutually exclusive:

```
#define USE_A
#define USE_B
#define USE_C
```

Example of mutually exclusive:

```
#define BUILD_FULL
#define BUILD_COMPACT
```

Until now I selected the configuration of the program to compile by documenting out the features I don't want to use, for example:

```
//#define BUILD_FULL
#define BUILD_COMPACT
```

to build a COMPACT executable.

How can I write documentation for the commented out features?

I tried:

```
#define USE_A //!< Special Feature
#define USE_B //!< Special Feature
//#define USE_C //!< Special Feature
```

I compiled it without `USE_C` but obviously I lost the documentation because doxygen didn't parse it. How would you rewrite the `#define` flow if I misunderstand the right way of using defines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test for the *value* of the macro, instead of just its presence. For example, use 0 to disable an option, or 1 to enable it. Then, use `#if` instead of `#ifdef` to test the condition.

```
#define USE_A 1    //!< Special Feature
#define USE_B 1    //!< Special Feature
#define USE_C 0    //!< Special Feature

#if USE_A
...
#elif USE_C
...
#endif
```

Comment: Yes I already figure that in this way I can leave the define in the proper place and so the code is visible everywhere. The only problem is that I need to edit all my code :( Time to monkey patching :)